# PostgreSQL external C function link failed on Mac OSX

Tags: c++, macos, postgresql

I'm trying to build an external `PostgreSQL` function on `OSX 10.11` with both `clang` and `gcc`, but link failed with the following errors:

`c++ -I/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/include/server -fpic -c ./main.c`

```
c++ -shared -o ttt.dylib main.o 
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_deconstruct_array", referenced from:
  _psql_nearest in main.o
  "_elog_finish", referenced from:
  _psql_nearest in main.o
  "_elog_start", referenced from:
  _psql_nearest in main.o
  "_get_typlenbyvalalign", referenced from:
  _psql_nearest in main.o
  "_pfree", referenced from:
  _psql_nearest in main.o
  "_pg_detoast_datum", referenced from:
  _psql_nearest in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It looks like I need to link my library with some of `PostgreSQL` libraries. What are these libraries?

```
 main.cpp:

extern "C" {
    #include <postgres.h>
    #include <fmgr.h>
    #include <utils/array.h>
    #include <utils/lsyscache.h>
    #include <catalog/pg_type.h>

    #ifdef PG_MODULE_MAGIC
        PG_MODULE_MAGIC;
    #endif

    PG_FUNCTION_INFO_V1(psql_nearest);
    Datum psql_nearest(PG_FUNCTION_ARGS) {
        if(PG_ARGISNULL(0) || PG_ARGISNULL(1)) {
            elog(ERROR, "DOC2VEC: NULL INPUT DATA");
            PG_RETURN_NULL();
        }

        ArrayType *_docVector = PG_GETARG_ARRAYTYPE_P(0);
        Oid elTypeVals = ARR_ELEMTYPE(_docVector);
        if (elTypeVals != FLOAT4OID) {
            elog(ERROR, "DOC2VEC: INVALID INPUT DATA TYPE");
            PG_RETURN_NULL();
        }

        int16 typeLenVals = 0;
        bool typeByValVals = false;
        char typeAlignVals = char(0);
        get_typlenbyvalalign(elTypeVals, &typeLenVals, &typeByValVals, &typeAlignVals);

        Datum *inputVals;
        bool *nullVals;
        int nVals;
        deconstruct_array(_docVector, elTypeVals, typeLenVals, typeByValVals, typeAlignVals, &inputVals, &nullVals, &nVals);

        pfree(inputVals);
        pfree(nullVals);

        PG_RETURN_NULL();
    }
}
```

Comment: Just to be 100% clear: your edit changed the source code file from `main.c` to `main.cpp`, yet the `cc` command at the top still has `main.c`. That should be `main.cpp` as well, right? Or did you just change the name to explain the `extern "C"` part, but the actual file name is `main.c`. That's going to be confusing.

Comment: Try linking with `pgcommon`, among others. `pgfree lives there`.

Comment: Yes, I changed `main.c` to `main.cpp` and `cc` to `c++` to explain why do I need `extern "C"` section.  I was trying (unsuccessful) to link with `pgcommon`, `pgtypes`, `pgport` and `libpq`

Comment: I notice there is no dyn-lib for pgcommon. Instead, you may try to add `libpgcommon.a` to the linker instead. Not sure what's up with the lack of dylib files, but that could work as an alternative for now.

Comment: It solves only `_pfree` reference.

Comment: I assume the other references can be found in some of the other static libraries. I'm curious though, whether the so libraries on Linux do contain `pfree` and such (as the brew-ly installed dylib files don't).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to `PostgreSQL` developers, they explained me the difference in `Linux` and `OSX` linking of external functions.
Instead of `-shared` you need `-bundle -bundle_loader /path/to/postgres`,
and there are some other linker flags that are advisable too.
Also, `PostgreSQL` expects the file extension for loadable modules to be `.so` even on `OSX`.

It's usually better to use [PGXS](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/extend-pgxs.html) to build extensions, instead of
learning such details for yourself.
Or you can crib from one of the extensions in the contrib/
source tree.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to *link*, you will need the `-L` flag to point the linker to the path where the postgres libraries are located (the linker equivalent of the `-I` compiler flag). and the `-l` flag to actually link the libraries (one for each library); the library name without the `lib` prefix and without the extension.

In your case, something along the lines of `-L/usr/local/Cellar/postgresql/9.5.3/lib -lpostgres`

(There's a variety of library files in that directory; try `-lpg` to start with.
The reference to `_pfree` in your error message also suggest to link `pgcommon`, which contains the implementation of `pgree` (at least when using `nm libpgcommon.a`).
)

---

You may want to read up a bit more on compiling and linking in general; you do the right thing for compiling with the `-I` flag, but oddly then miss out on the linking step. And learning about `make` and Makefiles will come in handy.
I also don't understand the `extern "C" {` part for a `.c` file, which is clearly a C-only file. `extern "C"` is usually used in C++ files for compatibility with C.

Comment: Thank you, but the problem is that on Linux I do not need any libraries to link this PostgreSQL external C function.

Comment: I'm enough experienced in make tools etc, my question is what libraries do I need on OSX for successful linking of a PostgreSQL external C function.  The extern "C" section is needed because I use C++ code inside of the psql_nearest function.

Comment: In that case, a bit of searching should let you find the libraries. You don't require linker path flags on Linux, because the files are in standard locations. You do, however, also require the `-l` flag to link with the postgres library. If you don't need that, there's something fishy (or a non-standard setting): even the standard math library requires `-lm` on Linux.

Comment: I can not google any solution, so I'm asking here. There are no any problems with this code on Linux, as well as linked library does not depends on any postgres specific or libm etc -  `ldd ./ttt.so`  `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffd8fea1000)`  `libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f9494e84000)`  `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00005651a1b4a000)`

Comment: The reference to `_pfree` in your error message does seem to suggest the need for a postgres library, though.